# Extracting file matching bro signature

Tags: bro

I've written a signature to match small  `iframes` in `http responses`.

This works fine and I get an entry in `signatures.log` and `notice.log`.

I'd like to extract any files which hit this `sig` so I can have a closer look, If I look at the `signature_match` event I can see the `http` content in the data variable -

should I just output this data to a file or is there a way to use the `file_extract` functionality to extract the file correctly.

I'd like to extend this with more `sigs` so the file extract is my preferred method.

Should I be catching the `sig_match` event and then "call" file extract or catch the file_new event and somehow match the `sig` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something simple that has a caveat.  This will only match up to the first 4096 bytes of a file by using the bof_buffer (Begin Of File buffer) that is given with the `fa_file` record.  We can look into that record with the `file_sniff` event to see if what you are looking for can be found there.

```bro
event file_sniff(f: fa_file, meta: fa_metadata)
    {
    if ( /<[iI][fF][rR][aA][mM][eE][[:blank:]]/ in f$bof_buffer )
        {
        Files::add_analyzer(f, Files::ANALYZER_EXTRACT);
        }
    }
```

What makes the caveat of this a little less important is that you don't actually have the opportunity to extract the complete file after the `file_sniff` event anyway.  Bro always operates on data in a streaming fashion and it doesn't keep things in memory forever so we only maintain this small buffer to allow us to make a decision on the file before we flush it to analyzers (such as the file extract analyzer).

Are you actually looking to extract the entire file or are you just looking to extract the url of the iframe?

Comment: I'm looking to extract the entire file - I was hoping to be able to define a load of file pattern regular expressions in a .sig file and, using the signature_match event, extract any files which hit a signature. This would mean that the hit would be logged in signatures.log and the file would be saved to disk for further analysis.